# Typescript cannot infer type when I use Bluebird.promisifyAll

Tags: typescript, bluebird

I want to use Bluebird to promiseAll nodejs `fs` modules with `Typescript`

My codes

```
import * as FS from 'fs'

const fs = Bluebird.promisifyAll(FS)

interface fs{
    readFileAsync: Function
}
```

But when I use `fs.readFileAsync()`

tsc tell me

```
[ts] Property 'readFileAsync' does not exist on type 'typeof import("fs")'. Did you mean 'readFileSync'? [2551]
```

---

**How can I do to tell tsc 'Hi, there also have a function called readFileAsync in fs object'?**

Comment: Are you sure `fs.readFileAsync` exists? If you are talking about the Node File System module, that does not contain a `readFileAsync` function.

Comment: Incidentally, Node v10 and up have [`fs.promises`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), a namespace that implements each of the functions as async.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an interface called `fs` does not automatically make the `fs` constant implement it.

If you want to manually write that function, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
import * as FS from 'fs'

interface fs {
    readFileAsync: Function
}

const fsWithReadFileAsync: fs = {
    ...Bluebird.promisifyAll(FS),
    readFileAsync: () => {
        // Implement your function here
    }
}

fsWithReadFileAsync.readFileAsync()
```